# Excel formula for increasing the row number in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Please. The formula already posted for increasing the row number while dragging across

`columns.(=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-1,)`

Want to drag down formula in rows, increasing the column letter, using same type of formula with offset?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need? 
 `=OFFSET($A$1,row())-1`

this row() function return the row number of that cell. you should modify that `-1` to adjust the result to acurate number.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.